# Guidance on architecting an Blazor App for Background Processes

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, blazor

I am looking for direction on how to approach this.  This is a personal project of mine to learn more about web technologies since the last time I touched this stuff was when `Macromedia` was still in business.

I have two programs.  Both are `.NET CORE 3.1` and written in `C#`.

- `Email` console app
- `Blazor` server-side single page web app

The `Email` console app runs every `15 minutes` to check to see if a `Google Gmail` account received any new emails.  If it does certain meta data from the emails will be parsed and stored in a `SQL` database.  Yes, I know I don’t have to poll the email every `15 minutes` since `Google` has push support.

The `Blazor` web app is just an `HTML` table where individual table cells get updated based on `SQL` database changes in a real-time fashion.  You can think of this table as a dashboard of sorts.

Right now both programs run on my system.

Now, my question is:

If I wanted to get rid of the `Email` console app and replace its functionality in the `Blazor` web app what libraries or techniques would I use to have a background service automatically poll the `Gmail` account every `15 minutes`.  I am quite proficient with `C#` but when it comes to web stuff I am still a noob so I am just looking for stuff to research to learn more.  Unsure if a `Microservice` will make sense.

Thank you for any suggestions.  Eventually, my plan it to host this `Blazor` web app in `Microsoft Azure` for my personal usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're doing this for our WebAssembly application (probably similar for Blazor-server), and the way we implemented it is using `hosted services` in .NET Core. See [these microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

On your server, in Startup.cs, you initialize a hosted service inside `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

```
// Start up a background service / watcher to monitor fatal errors
services.AddHostedService<FatalExceptionMonitor>();
```

Then our `FatalExceptionMonitor` class inherits from `BackgroundService`, and has a method `ExecuteAsync` that gets automatically called:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    // The way background services run every X minutes is putting a Task.Delay inside a while loop
    while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {

        try
        {
            // Do stuff here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        // The way background services run every X minutes is putting a Task.Delay inside a while loop
        // Pause for X minutes
        int.TryParse(_configuration["FatalExceptionMonitor:HowOftenToRunInMinutes"], out int HowOftenToRunInMinutes);
        await Task.Delay(1000 * 60 * HowOftenToRunInMinutes, cancelToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Exactly what I was looking for.  The IHostedService interface documentation provided looks perfect.